# TypeError: String cannot represent value: graphql Query not working

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo

I am trying to run a graphql Query but it keeps giving me the "TypeError: String cannot represent value:" error.

The schema for my query:

```
    type User {
        active: Boolean!
        email: String!
        fullname: String!
        description: String!
        tags: [String!]!
    }

    type Query {
        getAllUsers: [User]!
    }
```

My resolver:

```
Query: {
        getAllUsers: (_, __, { dataSources }) => {
            return dataSources.userAPI.getAllUsers();
        }
    }
```

userAPI:

```js
    getAllUsers() {
        const params = {
            TableName: 'Users',
            Select: 'ALL_ATTRIBUTES'
        };

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            dynamodb.scan(params, function(err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('Error: ', err);
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    console.log('Success');
                    resolve(data.Items);
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

The query:

```
query getAllUsers{
  getAllUsers{
    email
  }
}
```

Since my email is a string, the error I'm getting is "String cannot represent value".

Comment: input setInput {
  email: String!
}              

getAllUsers(input: setInput): [User]

Comment: Please tell me what you want? are you want user object with condition like email address or other value

Comment: @MaheshBhatnagar I am expecting the query to return an array of the user emails. No need for an input as I'm trying to return all of them so I'm not setting any conditions

Comment: Please write that query
 
query getAllUsers{
  getAllUsers{
    User[email]
  }
}

Comment: that wouldnt work, can't include [] in queries. Now it's giving me syntax errors

Comment: ok i am checking

Comment: Please use that query 
getAllUsers{ getAllUsers{ User{email} } }

Comment: No, that wont work because it will be looking for the field User within my User type

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201635/discussion-between-mahesh-bhatnagar-and-kaisin-li).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What's returned inside your resolver should match the shape specified by your schema. If your User schema is

```
type User {
  active: Boolean!
  email: String!
  fullname: String!
  description: String!
  tags: [String!]!
}
```

then the array of Users you return should look like this:

```
[{
  active: true,
  email: 'kaisinnn@li.com',
  fullname: 'Kaisin Li',
  description: 'Test',
  tags: ['SOME_TAG']
}]
```

The data you're actually returning is shaped much differently:

```
[{
  active: {
    BOOL: true
  },
  description: {
    S: 'Test'
  },
  fullname: {
    S: 'Kaisin Li'
  },
  email: {
    S: 'kaisinnn@li.com'
  },
}]
```

You need to *either* map over the array you're getting from the scan operation and transform the result into the correct shape, or write a resolver for each individual field. For example:

```
const resolvers = {
  User: {
    active: (user) => user.active.BOOL,
    description: (user) => user.description.S,
    // and so on
  }
}
```